# bigger than I have ever seen

Tags: meaning, pronouns, comparative

a. That cat is bigger than I have ever seen.

b. That cat is bigger than I have ever seen it.

Is there a difference between the meanings of these sentences?

I think 'a cat bigger than I have ever seen' means 'the biggest cat I have ever seen'.

But does (a) mean that cat is the biggest I have ever seen? Or does it mean the same as (b)?

Many thanks

Comment: The first (a) is ambiguous, and additional words are required to resolve the ambiguity, e.g. That cat is bigger than I have ever seen. _Most tabbies are smaller/what have you been feeding him?_.

Answer (score 1):

A does mean that the cat mentioned is the biggest cat the speaker has ever seen.

B means that the cat mentioned has become bigger than I have ever seen it before. The word "it" refers to that cat, which has grown bigger since I last saw it.

Comment: What about _Your mother is bigger than I have ever seen_?

Comment: What about *Your mother is bigger than I have ever seen her?*

Comment: I was trying to hint that A could refer to a particular cat's present versus previous size.

Comment: I guess you could read it that way. But. I think that sense would usually be said with a reflexive ending- him,her or it.

Answer (score 0):

(b) means that cat has grown bigger than you have ever seen it before.  It is the same cat.

(a) is ambiguous and is different from (b).

Edit

To mean 'the biggest cat I have ever seen', we say "a cat bigger than **any**  I have ever seen".  We are comparing different cats.  For (a) to take that meaning, we would need the additional **any** or equivalent.

> That cat is bigger than **any**  I have ever seen.

Edit

or more idiomatically, as @Kate suggested,

> (a) That cat is the biggest I have ever seen.

Comment: Or, more idiomatically, **(a) That cat is the biggest I have ever seen**.

Comment: A cat is not anyone. That cat is bigger than any cat I have ever seen.